# how to read jvm crash report? What could be the reason of the report

Tags: java, crash, jvm, crash-dumps, crash-reports

How to read below jvm crash report in Linux box? What could be the issue for this? This issues is coming while we pdf from on server to other transfer.

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

> SIGSEGV (0xb) at
>   pc=0x00002aaaab26df31, pid=8070,
>   tid=1092516160
>
> JRE version: 6.0_19-b04  Java VM:
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   (16.2-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 ) 
>   Problematic frame:  C 
>   [libzip.so+0xaf31]
>
> If you would like to submit a bug
>   report, please visit:
>   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
>   The crash happened outside the Java
>   Virtual Machine in native code.  See
>   problematic frame for where to report
>   the bug.
>
> ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
>
> Current thread (0x000000004fae8000): 
>   JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native,
>   id=8071,
>   stack(0x00000000410e7000,0x00000000411e8000)]
>
> siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0,
>   si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR),
>   si_addr=0x00002aa7afd2e04e
>
> Registers: RAX=0x0000000000000000,
>   RBX=0x000000004fecf6e0,
>   RCX=0x00002ae16ff59a00,
>   RDX=0x000000004fd00f90
>   RSP=0x00000000411e6700,
>   RBP=0x00002aa7afd2e031,
>   RSI=0x00002ae16ff599f8,
>   RDI=0x000000004fd00f90 R8
>   =0x0000000000000003, R9 =0x00002ae170870b81, R10=0x0000000000000000,
>   R11=0x00002aaaab26e300
>   R12=0x000000004fd00fa0,
>   R13=0x000000004fe3a7b0,
>   R14=0x00000000411e6800,
>   R15=0x000000004fae8000
>   RIP=0x00002aaaab26df31,
>   EFL=0x0000000000010202,
>   CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033,
>   ERR=0x0000000000000004
>   TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e
>
> Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000411e6700)
>   0x00000000411e6700:   00000000411e6720
>   0000000000000000 0x00000000411e6710:
>   000000004fe3a7b0 00002aaaae5a7500
>   0x00000000411e6720:   00002aaaae68c138
>   00000000411e6800 0x00000000411e6730:
>   000000004fae8000 00002aaaab26e351
>   0x00000000411e6740:   00002ae170870b81
>   00002aaaae68c138 0x00000000411e6750:
>   00000000411e67d0 00002aaaab2667ce
>   0x00000000411e6760:   000000004fae8900
>   00002aaaab388986 0x00000000411e6770:
>   00000000411e6858 00002aaaab393e23
>   0x00000000411e6780:   000000004fae8000
>   00002aaa00000000 0x00000000411e6790:
>   00000000411e6790 00002aaaae68c138
>   0x00000000411e67a0:   00000000411e6800
>   00002aaaae68df10 0x00000000411e67b0:
>   0000000000000000 00002aaaae68c138
>   0x00000000411e67c0:   0000000000000000
>   00000000411e67f0 0x00000000411e67d0:
>   00000000411e6848 00002aaaab37c973
>   0x00000000411e67e0:   00002aaaae68d910
>   00002aaaab385897 0x00000000411e67f0:
>   0000000000000000 000000004fe3a7b0
>   0x00000000411e6800:   000000004fae8000
>   00000000411e6808 0x00000000411e6810:
>   00002aaaae68ce6a 00000000411e6868
>   0x00000000411e6820:   00002aaaae68df10
>   0000000000000000 0x00000000411e6830:
>   00002aaaae68ce78 00000000411e67f0
>   0x00000000411e6840:   00000000411e6858
>   00000000411e68c0 0x00000000411e6850:
>   00002aaaab37c973 0000000000000000
>   0x00000000411e6860:   000000004fe3a7b0
>   00002aab5b304410 0x00000000411e6870:
>   0000000000000001 00002aab5b304410
>   0x00000000411e6880:   00000000411e6870
>   00002aaaaea23b4e 0x00000000411e6890:
>   00000000411e68f8 00002aaaaea240c0
>   0x00000000411e68a0:   0000000000000000
>   00002aaaaea23c08 0x00000000411e68b0:
>   00000000411e6858 00000000411e68f8
>   0x00000000411e68c0:   00000000411e6940
>   00002aaaab37c8e9 0x00000000411e68d0:
>   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
>   0x00000000411e68e0:   0000000000000000
>   0000000000000000 0x00000000411e68f0:
>   00002aab5b304410 00002aab5b3046f0
>
> Instructions: (pc=0x00002aaaab26df31)
>   0x00002aaaab26df21:   28 00 00 00 00
>   8b 6b 04 49 03 6d 18 49 2b 6d 28
>   0x00002aaaab26df31:   0f b6 45 1d 0f
>   b6 5d 1c 44 0f b6 75 1e 44 0f b6
>
> Stack:
>   [0x00000000410e7000,0x00000000411e8000],
>   sp=0x00000000411e6700,  free
>   space=3fd0000000000000018k Native
>   frames: (J=compiled Java code,
>   j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native
>   code) C  [libzip.so+0xaf31]
>
> Java frames: (J=compiled Java code,
>   j=interpreted, Vv=VM code) j 
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.getNextEntry(JI)J+0
>   j 
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$400(JI)J+2
>   j 
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$2.nextElement()Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;+54
>   j 
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$2.nextElement()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
>   j 
>   com.apple.iknow.infomanager.worldserver.FSHandler.setBatchFileName(Ljava/lang/String;)V+58
>   j 
>   com.apple.iknow.infomanager.worldserver.BatchMover.sendBatch(Ljava/lang/String;)V+26
>   j 
>   com.apple.iknow.infomanager.worldserver.BatchMover.sendBatches()V+137
>   j 
>   com.apple.iknow.infomanager.worldserver.BatchMover.processBatches()V+62
>   j 
>   com.apple.iknow.infomanager.worldserver.BatchMover.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+14
>   v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
>
> ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------
>
> Java Threads: ( => current thread )
>   0x000000004fb76800 JavaThread "Low
>   Memory Detector" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=8098,
>   stack(0x0000000041b63000,0x0000000041c64000)]
>   0x000000004fb74800 JavaThread
>   "CompilerThread1" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=8097,
>   stack(0x0000000041a62000,0x0000000041b63000)]
>   0x000000004fb6f800 JavaThread
>   "CompilerThread0" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=8096,
>   stack(0x000000004156d000,0x000000004166e000)]
>   0x000000004fb6d800 JavaThread "Signal
>   Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked,
>   id=8095,
>   stack(0x000000004146c000,0x000000004156d000)]
>   0x000000004fb4a000 JavaThread
>   "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked,
>   id=8080,
>   stack(0x0000000041961000,0x0000000041a62000)]
>   0x000000004fb48000 JavaThread
>   "Reference Handler" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=8079,
>   stack(0x0000000041860000,0x0000000041961000)]
>   =>0x000000004fae8000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=8071,
>   stack(0x00000000410e7000,0x00000000411e8000)]
>
> Other Threads:   0x000000004fb43800
>   VMThread [stack:
>   0x000000004175f000,0x0000000041860000]
>   [id=8076]   0x000000004fb79800
>   WatcherThread [stack:
>   0x0000000041c64000,0x0000000041d65000]
>   [id=8099]
>
> VM state:not at safepoint (normal
>   execution)
>
> VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a
>   thread: None
>
> Heap  PSYoungGen      total 74944K,
>   used 6436K [0x00002aab5ada0000,
>   0x00002aab60140000,
>   0x00002aabae840000)   eden space
>   64256K, 10% used
>   [0x00002aab5ada0000,0x00002aab5b3e9050,0x00002aab5ec60000)
>   from space 10688K, 0% used
>   [0x00002aab5f6d0000,0x00002aab5f6d0000,0x00002aab60140000)
>   to   space 10688K, 0% used
>   [0x00002aab5ec60000,0x00002aab5ec60000,0x00002aab5f6d0000)
>   PSOldGen        total 171392K, used 0K
>   [0x00002aaab3840000,
>   0x00002aaabdfa0000,
>   0x00002aab5ada0000)   object space
>   171392K, 0% used
>   [0x00002aaab3840000,0x00002aaab3840000,0x00002aaabdfa0000)
>   PSPermGen       total 21248K, used
>   6032K [0x00002aaaae440000,
>   0x00002aaaaf900000,
>   0x00002aaab3840000)   object space
>   21248K, 28% used
>   [0x00002aaaae440000,0x00002aaaaea24368,0x00002aaaaf900000)
>
> Dynamic libraries: 40000000-40009000
>   r-xp 00000000 ca:03 813433
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/bin/java
>   40108000-4010a000 rwxp 00008000 ca:03
>   813433
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/bin/java
>   405d7000-405d8000 ---p 405d7000 00:00
>   0  405d8000-406d8000 rwxp 405d8000
>   00:00 0  40e74000-40e75000 ---p
>   40e74000 00:00 0  40e75000-40f75000
>   rwxp 40e75000 00:00 0 
>   40f75000-40f76000 ---p 40f75000 00:00
>   0  40f76000-41076000 rwxp 40f76000
>   00:00 0  410e7000-410ea000 ---p
>   410e7000 00:00 0  410ea000-411e8000
>   rwxp 410ea000 00:00 0 
>   411e8000-411e9000 ---p 411e8000 00:00
>   0  411e9000-412e9000 rwxp 411e9000
>   00:00 0  4146c000-4146f000 ---p
>   4146c000 00:00 0  4146f000-4156d000
>   rwxp 4146f000 00:00 0 
>   4156d000-41570000 ---p 4156d000 00:00
>   0  41570000-4166e000 rwxp 41570000
>   00:00 0  4175f000-41760000 ---p
>   4175f000 00:00 0  41760000-41860000
>   rwxp 41760000 00:00 0 
>   41860000-41863000 ---p 41860000 00:00
>   0  41863000-41961000 rwxp 41863000
>   00:00 0  41961000-41964000 ---p
>   41961000 00:00 0  41964000-41a62000
>   rwxp 41964000 00:00 0 
>   41a62000-41a65000 ---p 41a62000 00:00
>   0  41a65000-41b63000 rwxp 41a65000
>   00:00 0  41b63000-41b66000 ---p
>   41b63000 00:00 0  41b66000-41c64000
>   rwxp 41b66000 00:00 0 
>   41c64000-41c65000 ---p 41c64000 00:00
>   0  41c65000-41d65000 rwxp 41c65000
>   00:00 0  4fae1000-4feee000 rwxp
>   4fae1000 00:00 0
>   [heap] 2aaaaaaab000-2aaaaaaad000 r-xs
>   0000c000 00:1e 1251770
>   /ngs/app/fsnp/oa/fsnusrp/CRMBASE/Scopes/iknow/batchMover/lib/activation.jar
>   2aaaaaaad000-2aaaaaaaf000 r-xs
>   00006000 00:1e 239190
>   /ngs/app/fsnp/oa/fsnusrp/CRMBASE/Scopes/iknow/batchMover/lib/batch-mover.jar
>   2aaaaaab4000-2aaaaaabb000 r-xp
>   00000000 ca:03 1105447
>   /lib64/librt-2.5.so
>   2aaaaaabb000-2aaaaacbb000 ---p
>   00007000 ca:03 1105447
>   /lib64/librt-2.5.so
>   2aaaaacbb000-2aaaaacbc000 r-xp
>   00007000 ca:03 1105447
>   /lib64/librt-2.5.so
>   2aaaaacbc000-2aaaaacbd000 rwxp
>   00008000 ca:03 1105447
>   /lib64/librt-2.5.so
>   2aaaaacbd000-2aaaaacca000 r-xp
>   00000000 ca:03 911642
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
>   2aaaaacca000-2aaaaadc9000 ---p
>   0000d000 ca:03 911642
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
>   2aaaaadc9000-2aaaaadcc000 rwxp
>   0000c000 ca:03 911642
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
>   2aaaaadcc000-2aaaaadf5000 r-xp
>   00000000 ca:03 911621
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
>   2aaaaadf5000-2aaaaaef4000 ---p
>   00029000 ca:03 911621
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
>   2aaaaaef4000-2aaaaaefb000 rwxp
>   00028000 ca:03 911621
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
>   2aaaaaefb000-2aaaaaefc000 r-xp
>   2aaaaaefb000 00:00 0 
>   2aaaaaefc000-2aaaaaefd000 rwxp
>   2aaaaaefc000 00:00 0 
>   2aaaaaf03000-2aaaaaf18000 r-xp
>   00000000 ca:03 1105429
>   /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
>   2aaaaaf18000-2aaaab117000 ---p
>   00015000 ca:03 1105429
>   /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
>   2aaaab117000-2aaaab118000 r-xp
>   00014000 ca:03 1105429
>   /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
>   2aaaab118000-2aaaab119000 rwxp
>   00015000 ca:03 1105429
>   /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
>   2aaaab119000-2aaaab11b000 rwxp
>   2aaaab119000 00:00 0 
>   2aaaab11b000-2aaaab122000 r-xp
>   00000000 ca:03 911647
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
>   2aaaab122000-2aaaab223000 ---p
>   00007000 ca:03 911647
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
>   2aaaab223000-2aaaab225000 rwxp
>   00008000 ca:03 911647
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
>   2aaaab225000-2aaaab226000 rwxp
>   2aaaab225000 00:00 0 
>   2aaaab226000-2aaaab25b000 r-xs
>   00000000 ca:02 192194
>   /var/db/nscd/passwd
>   2aaaab25b000-2aaaab263000 rwxs
>   00000000 ca:05 63814
>   /tmp/hsperfdata_fsnusrp/8070
>   2aaaab263000-2aaaab271000 r-xp
>   00000000 ca:03 911643
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
>   2aaaab271000-2aaaab373000 ---p
>   0000e000 ca:03 911643
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
>   2aaaab373000-2aaaab376000 rwxp
>   00010000 ca:03 911643
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
>   2aaaab376000-2aaaab5e7000 rwxp
>   2aaaab376000 00:00 0 
>   2aaaab5e7000-2aaaae377000 rwxp
>   2aaaab5e7000 00:00 0 
>   2aaaae377000-2aaaae381000 rwxp
>   2aaaae377000 00:00 0 
>   2aaaae381000-2aaaae437000 rwxp
>   2aaaae381000 00:00 0 
>   2aaaae440000-2aaaaf900000 rwxp
>   2aaaae440000 00:00 0 
>   2aaaaf900000-2aaab3840000 rwxp
>   2aaaaf900000 00:00 0 
>   2aaab3840000-2aaabdfa0000 rwxp
>   2aaab3840000 00:00 0 
>   2aaabdfa0000-2aab5ada0000 rwxp
>   2aaabdfa0000 00:00 0 
>   2aab5ada0000-2aab60140000 rwxp
>   2aab5ada0000 00:00 0 
>   2aab60140000-2aabae840000 rwxp
>   2aab60140000 00:00 0 
>   2aabae840000-2aabae84b000 rwxp
>   2aabae840000 00:00 0 
>   2aabae84b000-2aabae86a000 rwxp
>   2aabae84b000 00:00 0 
>   2aabae86a000-2aabae8be000 rwxp
>   2aabae86a000 00:00 0 
>   2aabae8be000-2aabaeda4000 rwxp
>   2aabae8be000 00:00 0 
>   2aabaeda4000-2aabaedcf000 rwxp
>   2aabaeda4000 00:00 0 
>   2aabaedcf000-2aabaf042000 rwxp
>   2aabaedcf000 00:00 0 
>   2aabaf042000-2aabaf097000 rwxp
>   2aabaf042000 00:00 0 
>   2aabaf097000-2aabaf57e000 rwxp
>   2aabaf097000 00:00 0 
>   2aabaf57e000-2aabaf589000 rwxp
>   2aabaf57e000 00:00 0 
>   2aabaf589000-2aabaf5a8000 rwxp
>   2aabaf589000 00:00 0 
>   2aabaf5a8000-2aabaf5d0000 rwxp
>   2aabaf5a8000 00:00 0 
>   2aabaf5d0000-2aabaf766000 r-xs
>   02fd0000 ca:03 913212
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/rt.jar
>   2aabaf766000-2aabafc9e000 rwxp
>   2aabaf766000 00:00 0 
>   2aabafc9e000-2aabafcd2000 r-xs
>   00295000 00:1e 1251772
>   /ngs/app/fsnp/oa/fsnusrp/CRMBASE/Scopes/iknow/batchMover/lib/cayenne.jar
>   2aabafcd2000-2aabafcd3000 r-xs
>   0000d000 00:1e 1251774
>   /ngs/app/fsnp/oa/fsnusrp/CRMBASE/Scopes/iknow/batchMover/lib/java-getopt-1.0.13.jar
>   2aabafcf5000-2aabafcfa000 r-xs
>   00028000 00:1e 1251773
>   /ngs/app/fsnp/oa/fsnusrp/CRMBASE/Scopes/iknow/batchMover/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar
>   2aabafcfa000-2aabafd02000 r-xs
>   0004f000 00:1e 1251775
>   /ngs/app/fsnp/oa/fsnusrp/CRMBASE/Scopes/iknow/batchMover/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar
>   2aabafd28000-2aabafd2e000 r-xs
>   0004a000 00:1e 1251776
>   /ngs/app/fsnp/oa/fsnusrp/CRMBASE/Scopes/iknow/batchMover/lib/mail.jar
>   2aabafd2e000-2aabafd54000 r-xs
>   423004000 00:1f 12542841
>   /nfs/na16iknow/iknowp01/translation/export/ZSM_2010_1222_b1.zip
>   2aabb0000000-2aabb01cc000 rwxp
>   2aabb0000000 00:00 0 
>   2aabb01cc000-2aabb4000000 ---p
>   2aabb01cc000 00:00 0 
>   2ae16f4c0000-2ae16f4dc000 r-xp
>   00000000 ca:03 1105412
>   /lib64/ld-2.5.so
>   2ae16f4dc000-2ae16f4dd000 rwxp
>   2ae16f4dc000 00:00 0 
>   2ae16f4e5000-2ae16f4e6000 rwxp
>   2ae16f4e5000 00:00 0 
>   2ae16f6db000-2ae16f6dc000 r-xp
>   0001b000 ca:03 1105412
>   /lib64/ld-2.5.so
>   2ae16f6dc000-2ae16f6dd000 rwxp
>   0001c000 ca:03 1105412
>   /lib64/ld-2.5.so
>   2ae16f6dd000-2ae16f6f3000 r-xp
>   00000000 ca:03 1105443
>   /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
>   2ae16f6f3000-2ae16f8f2000 ---p
>   00016000 ca:03 1105443
>   /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
>   2ae16f8f2000-2ae16f8f3000 r-xp
>   00015000 ca:03 1105443
>   /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
>   2ae16f8f3000-2ae16f8f4000 rwxp
>   00016000 ca:03 1105443
>   /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
>   2ae16f8f4000-2ae16f8f8000 rwxp
>   2ae16f8f4000 00:00 0 
>   2ae16f8f8000-2ae16f8ff000 r-xp
>   00000000 ca:03 911604
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
>   2ae16f8ff000-2ae16fa00000 ---p
>   00007000 ca:03 911604
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
>   2ae16fa00000-2ae16fa02000 rwxp
>   00008000 ca:03 911604
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
>   2ae16fa02000-2ae16fa04000 r-xp
>   00000000 ca:03 1105425
>   /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
>   2ae16fa04000-2ae16fc04000 ---p
>   00002000 ca:03 1105425
>   /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
>   2ae16fc04000-2ae16fc05000 r-xp
>   00002000 ca:03 1105425
>   /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
>   2ae16fc05000-2ae16fc06000 rwxp
>   00003000 ca:03 1105425
>   /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
>   2ae16fc06000-2ae16fc07000 rwxp
>   2ae16fc06000 00:00 0 
>   2ae16fc07000-2ae16fd54000 r-xp
>   00000000 ca:03 1105419
>   /lib64/libc-2.5.so
>   2ae16fd54000-2ae16ff54000 ---p
>   0014d000 ca:03 1105419
>   /lib64/libc-2.5.so
>   2ae16ff54000-2ae16ff58000 r-xp
>   0014d000 ca:03 1105419
>   /lib64/libc-2.5.so
>   2ae16ff58000-2ae16ff59000 rwxp
>   00151000 ca:03 1105419
>   /lib64/libc-2.5.so
>   2ae16ff59000-2ae16ff5f000 rwxp
>   2ae16ff59000 00:00 0 
>   2ae16ff5f000-2ae170714000 r-xp
>   00000000 ca:03 911651
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
>   2ae170714000-2ae170813000 ---p
>   007b5000 ca:03 911651
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
>   2ae170813000-2ae17099e000 rwxp
>   007b4000 ca:03 911651
>   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
>   2ae17099e000-2ae1709d7000 rwxp
>   2ae17099e000 00:00 0 
>   2ae1709df000-2ae170a61000 r-xp
>   00000000 ca:03 1105427
>   /lib64/libm-2.5.so
>   2ae170a61000-2ae170c60000 ---p
>   00082000 ca:03 1105427
>   /lib64/libm-2.5.so
>   2ae170c60000-2ae170c61000 r-xp
>   00081000 ca:03 1105427
>   /lib64/libm-2.5.so
>   2ae170c61000-2ae170c62000 rwxp
>   00082000 ca:03 1105427
>   /lib64/libm-2.5.so
>   7fff56df4000-7fff56e09000 rwxp
>   7ffffffea000 00:00 0
>   [stack]
>   ffffffffff600000-ffffffffffe00000 ---p
>   00000000 00:00 0
>   [vdso]
>
> VM Arguments: java_command:
>   com.apple.iknow.infomanager.worldserver.BatchMover
>   -s Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
>
> Environment Variables:
>   PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/bin
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19/jre/../lib/amd64
>   SHELL=/bin/sh
>
> Signal Handlers: SIGSEGV:
>   [libjvm.so+0x70ffd0],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGBUS:
>   [libjvm.so+0x70ffd0],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGFPE:
>   [libjvm.so+0x5d8cf0],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGPIPE:
>   [libjvm.so+0x5d8cf0],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGXFSZ:
>   [libjvm.so+0x5d8cf0],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGILL:
>   [libjvm.so+0x5d8cf0],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL,
>   sa_mask[0]=0x00000000,
>   sa_flags=0x00000000 SIGUSR2:
>   [libjvm.so+0x5db510],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x00000000,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGHUP:
>   [libjvm.so+0x5db260],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGINT:
>   [libjvm.so+0x5db260],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGTERM:
>   [libjvm.so+0x5db260],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGQUIT:
>   [libjvm.so+0x5db260],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004
>
> ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------
>
> OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
>   release 5.4 (Tikanga)
>
> uname:Linux 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue
>   Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64
>   libc:glibc 2.5 NPTL 2.5  rlimit: STACK
>   10240k, CORE 0k, NPROC 133120, NOFILE
>   1024, AS infinity load average:0.00
>   0.00 0.00
>
> CPU:total 4 (32 cores per cpu, 2
>   threads per core) family 6 model 44
>   stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse,
>   sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, ht
>
> Memory: 4k page, physical
>   16447732k(6353056k free), swap
>   2096440k(2096320k free)
>
> vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM (16.2-b04) for linux-amd64
>   JRE (1.6.0_19-b04), built on Mar  9
>   2010 00:54:21 by "java_re" with gcc
>   3.2.2 (SuSE Linux)
>
> time: Tue Jan 11 21:05:01 2011 elapsed
>   time: 0 seconds

Comment: Try updating to the latest JVM (u24 now I think).

Answer (score 1):

C [libzip.so+0xaf31] indicates that there is an issue wtih libzip.so 
try to run with -Xcheck:jni option added to the command line.